# CRM mail merge and Word Macros/FILLINs

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using Microsoft CRM4 Mail merge function, which stores Word files as XML files inside CRM.  My client has a requirement to prompt the user for more information (not found in CRM) upon mail merging.

Previously, we used the Word 'FILLIN' commands, but it does not work with CRM mail merge as it only prompts the user before printing, not upon opening a Word file.

I attempted using Macros, but canno save macros to Microsoft Word 2003 XML file format.

My questions:
1. Is there any way to get 'FILLIN' to prompt the user upon opening the mail merged file?
2. Can I store macros in Word 2003 XML file format?
3. Any other way around it, that involves merging CRM records with a Word file, and prompting the user for more information not already found in CRM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an update, 
I ended up using Word macros, and each user has a copy of the Normal.dot template.  It's a far better solution as it's very customizable, but the downside is that every user has to have the normal.dot template and in Word 2003, it can get corrupted.